# R compare corresponding cells and create a new column named after the content

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm just starting with R and I though I've been doing pretty well, but this one killed me! :)

I've got a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
col1=letters[1:5],col2=c(NA,letters[4:1]),col3=letters[11:15],
col1_rr=letters[15:11], col2_rr=letters[2], col3_rr=c(letters[11:14], "oz"))
```

which looks like this:

```
     col1      col2    col3    col1_rr  col2_rr  col3_rr
 1     a        NA       k        o        b        k
 2     b        d        l        n        b        l
 3     c        c        m        m        b        m
 4     d        b        n        l        b        n
 5     e        a        o        k        b        oz
```

Note the pattern in column names. For each column `colX`, there's an equivalent of `colX_rr`.

Now, I want to check if the content of `df[1,"col1"]` is contained in `df[1,"col1_rr"]`.

For example, this statement is false for `df[1,"col1"]`, but true for all `col3` cells (even `df[5,"col3"]`, since `o` is contained in `oz`).

I know I can use `grepl` for that:

```
 > grepl(df[1,"col3"], df[1,"col3_rr"])
 [1] TRUE
 > grepl(df[2,"col1"], df[2,"col1_rr"])
 [1] FALSE
 > grepl(df[1,"col2"], df[1,"col2_rr"])
 [1] NA
 > grepl(df[5,"col3"], df[5,"col3_rr"])
 [1] TRUE
```

And next: generally speaking if the character `y` from `[z , colX]` is contained in the equivalent `[z , colX_rr]` cell, then I want to create a new column `y` and input `1` for the given row. If the character `y` from `[z , colX]` is NOT contained in the equivalent `[z , colX_rr]` then input `0` in `df$y`.

So I would have something like this in the end:

```
     col1      col2    col3    col1_rr  col2_rr  col3_rr     a        b (...)  k(...)
 1     a        NA       k        o        b        k        0        0        1
 2     b        d        l        n        b        l        0        0        0
 3     c        c        m        m        b        m        0        0        0
 4     d        b        n        l        b        n        0        1        0
 5     e        a        o        k        b        oz       0        0        0
```

In each cell of the column range `col1:col3` there's only one single letter and it occurs only once for each participant (row). The content of column range `col1_rr` : `col3_rr` is pretty messy and contains strings of different length, but each letter also exists only once for each row.

Note that `NA`s also occur in the table.

I want this to be automatised, because there're 50 columns in the real data. But if necessary I can write a separate line of script for each column.

The letters in the real data are from the range `letters[1:14]`, so there will be only 14 new columns in the end, each containing values 0 or 1 (or `TRUE`/`FALSE`, if this makes the solution any simpler).

I've been trying with `ifelse` and `merge` but don't know how to make them work for this problem, for such a complex rule.

Thanks!

Comment: What value would you put if for the first row, col1, col1_rr, col2, col2_rr are all, say, `a`? Would you still put 1 under "a" or because two columns have same value between them, you'll add them and put 2??

Comment: each letter will occur only once for col1:col3 and max once for col1_rr : col3_rr

Comment: will cor1, cor2 and cor3 always be a single letter alphabet?

Comment: Yes in this case, although I might need help with something more complex in the near future :) thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, but not very elegant. It uses the `reshape2` package :

```
df <- data.frame(col1=letters[1:5],col2=c(NA,letters[4:1]),col3=letters[11:15],
                 col1_rr=letters[15:11], col2_rr=letters[2], col3_rr=c(letters[11:14], "oz"))
col.vars <- names(df)[1:3]
colrr.vars <- names(df)[4:6]
df$id <- 1:nrow(df)
df.var <- melt(df[,c("id",col.vars)], id.vars="id")
df.var_rr<- melt(df[,c("id",colrr.vars)], id.vars="id")
let <- names(table(unlist(df[,1:3])))
m <- data.frame(sapply(let, function(l) df.var$value==l & grepl(l, df.var_rr$value)))
cbind(df, aggregate(m, list(df.var$id), sum))
```

Which gives :

```
  col1 col2 col3 col1_rr col2_rr col3_rr id Group.1 a  b c d e k l m n o
1    a <NA>    k       o       b       k  1       1 0 NA 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
2    b    d    l       n       b       l  2       2 0  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
3    c    c    m       m       b       m  3       3 0  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
4    d    b    n       l       b       n  4       4 0  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
5    e    a    o       k       b      oz  5       5 0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: No worries, it's not a beauty contest :) Worked great and is really easy for me to adjust to the real data set. Thanks.